# How to convert Tiff to Image object?

Tags: asp.net, image, tiff

This is the asp.net source for converting multi-page tiff file to one-page jpeg.

I used to MemoryStream class and then convert to the jpeg.

This is in Windows 2005, IIS6, Visual Studio 2008, and .NET Framework 2.0.

```
            MemoryStream ms = null;
            Image SrcImg = null;
            Image returnImage = null;
            try
            {
                SrcImg = Image.FromFile(@'d:\\test.tif');
                ms = new MemoryStream();
                FrameDimension FrDim = new FrameDimension(SrcImg.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
                SrcImg.SelectActiveFrame(FrDim, 17); // 17 page...
                SrcImg.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Tiff);
                // Prevent using images internal thumbnail
                SrcImg.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                SrcImg.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                //Save Aspect Ratio
                if (SrcImg.Width <= ImgWidth) ImgWidth = SrcImg.Width;
                int NewHeight = SrcImg.Height * ImgWidth / SrcImg.Width;
                if (NewHeight > ImgHeight)
                {
                    // Resize with height instead
                    ImgWidth  = SrcImg.Width * ImgHeight  / SrcImg.Height;
                    NewHeight = ImgHeight;
                }
                returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms).GetThumbnailImage(ImgWidth, NewHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero); }
```

but this code is well in Windows 2008, IIS7, Visual Studio 2010, and .NET Framework 4.0.

The Error eraise "**SelectActiveFrame**" sentence.

Here is the sample tiff file.   [[Mouse right click - Save as "test.tif"]](http://cfile10.uf.tistory.com/original/1352E435506EC32017F0D3)

What's the matter? or Any good solution?

Comment: Please post the complete code, with the snipped you've given the memory stream is only used somewhere in the blah-blah section and it's unusable in tracking down the problem.

Comment: what is the error for on the `SelectActiveFrame`?

Comment: @Veli This "blah" may not count much. I think it doesn't matter.

Comment: @White : A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Comment: @user1283146 : take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43267752/1233379).